# Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Braintree_Exception_Configuration' with message 'environment needs to be set.'

Tags: php, error-handling, braintree, uncaught-exception

How to set the environment? And how to rectify this error?

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Braintree_Exception_Configuration'

Comment: Perhaps as shown in the [quick start example in the Braintree docs](https://www.braintreepayments.com/docs/php)

Comment: errors displayed, but these type of error cant explained so pls hlp me

Comment: If you are having trouble integrating, I suggest you [get in touch with the Braintree support team](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Message is pretty selfexplanatory. You need to call

```
Braintree_Configuration::environment(...);
```

with proper parameter prior using BT, as it needs to know if you want to talk to production or sandbox.

Comment: in init code. next to place where you set `metchantId` and keys

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Braintree_Exception_Configuration' with message 'sandbox'

Comment: then next i wat to do i got trans id